# Undefined Symbol in ltspice code and what is heightened Def Con?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice

Thank you for your inputs.
I have attached the schematic.
I am using third party models for simulation. The problems seems to be with some unrecognizable attribute by LTspice.

[image: SCHEMATIC]

```
    'Circuit:C:\Users\ArvindGupta\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sym\ArvindParts\Draft3.asc Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})} Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}&v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))&v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}"Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}"Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}&v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))&v(b)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}|v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vss}},{{vdd}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))|v(b)>((vthresh)),((vss)),((vdd)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}}&v(b)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh))&v(b)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Questionable use of curly braces in "b§e_abmgate yint 0 v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}" Error: undefined symbol in: "if([v](a)>((vthresh)),((vdd)),((vss)))" Error on line 455 : .model u1:_u3:dd1 d(dis=10f rs=0.092 n= 1.087 eg=0.524025 xti=4 bv=120 ibv=900m cjo=1.35095e-09 vj=0.0243937 m=0.407632 fc=0.5 tt=2.79601e-09 kf=0 af=1)* Unrecognized parameter "dis" -- ignored WARNING: Specified period is not longer than the sum of Trise, Tfall, and Ton for v4.  Increasing period to 3.001 Limiting fall time of source v4 to 6.21725e-016 Instance "m:lo:1": Width narrower than recommended for a level 3 MOSFET. Instance "m:hi:1": Width narrower than recommended for a level 3 MOSFET. Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded. Heightened Def Con from 1.253e-006 +++++++to 1.253e-006 Heightened Def Con from 1.253e-006 to 1.253e-006 Heightened Def Con from 1.253e-006 to 1.26413e-006 Heightened Def Con from 2.51015e-006 to 2.51127e-006 Heightened Def Con from 5.00014e-006 to 5.0012e-006 Heightened Def Con from 6.24886e-006 to 6.25099e-006 Heightened Def Con from 1.25119e-005 to 1.25139e-005 Heightened Def Con from 1.25235e-005 to 1.25246e-005 Heightened Def Con from 1.37659e-005 to 1.37669e-005 Heightened Def Con from 1.50133e-005 to 1.50143e-005 Heightened Def Con from 1.62489e-005 to 1.6251e-005 `enter code here`Date: Thu Oct 03 22:15:20 2019 Total elapsed time: 360.144 seconds. tnom = 27 temp = 27 method = modified trap totiter = 3833632 traniter = 3833592 tranpoints = 1108127 accept = 798160 rejected = 317380 matrix size = 260 fillins = 157 solver = Normal Thread vector: 16.6/9.2[6] 21.3/3.9[6] 18.3/3.6[6] 0.8/1.5[1]  2592/500 Matrix Compiler1: 17.82 KB object code size  9.0/5.3/[2.3] Matrix Compiler2: 20.74 KB object code size  4.5/6.6/[1.7]'
```

Comment: I've edited your post to have a code block... But now it's up to you to actually ask a question.

Comment: Can't write an answer because of the hold, but it looks like you attributed a behavioral expression in an old-type VCVS (the `Epoly` in `[Misc]`). You can simply replace that with a proper behavioral source (`bv`). Don't forget to keep the `V=` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only one curly brace should be used in a statement:

```
v={if(v(a)>{{vthresh}},{{vdd}},{{vss}})}
```

should be

```
v={if(v(a)>vthresh,vdd,vss)}
```

also, another thing that you need to remember is you can only reference nodes. So if `vthresh` is a node, and you want the voltage, then do this `v(vthresh)` (I don't know what your voltage nodes are since you have not provided the schematic)

If so then this statement should read:

```
v={if(v(a)>v(vthresh),v(vdd),v(vss))}
```

if you have an if statement with an or, it should look like this:

```
if((v(a)>v(vthresh))|(v(b)>v(vthresh)),v(vss),v(vdd))
```

Comment: There can be two curly braces, it doesn't affect the result, and there's no need for curly braces in a behavioural source. Also, simply having `a>1|b<2` (or any similar example) is correctly interpreted by the parser, in fact, any number of arguments, and the precedence of evaluation is ennumerated in the help (`LTspice > Circuit Elements > B`).

Comment: You are right, but it's better practice to leave the curly braces out and put the parentheses around the expressions, so that's why I changed it.

Comment: 'VTHRESH' is not a node voltage.      I removed the xtra pair of curly braces and added in an assignment '=' after 'VALUE' .    Those "questionable use of curly braces" errors are gone.                             
But this still remains:                                                                                    
  'Error on line 455 : .model u1:_u3:dd1 d(dis=10f rs=0.092 n= 1.087 eg=0.524025 xti=4 bv=120 ibv=900m cjo=1.35095e-09 vj=0.0243937 m=0.407632 fc=0.5 tt=2.79601e-09 kf=0 af=1)
 * Unrecognized parameter "dis" -- ignored
'

Comment: @ArvindGupta When you wrote the question, you did not provide the netlist  This is the parameters that are acceptable for diode models in lt spice: http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Especially @VoltageSpike. Sorted out all the problems. One last thing though, what is "Heightened Def Con" ?

Comment: @ArvindGupta It means you having convergence problems (your circuit is not solvable) http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F